# How to save a webpage to a desired location in firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do i save the current webpage to a desired location using javascript in a firefox addon. I have a button. When the user clicks on the button i want a explorer window to open and save the file to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

use this function `downloadFile(title, url, fileType)` with appropriate arguments

```
function downloadFile(title, url, fileType) 
{
    var file = getDownloadFile(title, fileType);

    var persist = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);  
    var ios = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);  
    var uri = ios.newURI(url, null, null); 

    var target = ios.newFileURI(file) 
    var xfer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/transfer;1"]  
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransfer);  
    xfer.init(uri, target, "", null, null, null, persist);  
    persist.progressListener = xfer; 
    persist.saveURI(uri, null, null, null, null, file);

}

function getDownloadFile(defaultString, fileType) 
{
    var nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;

    var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
    fp.init(window, "Save As", nsIFilePicker.modeSave);
    try {
        var urlExt = defaultString.substr(defaultString.lastIndexOf(".")+1, 3);
        if (urlExt!=fileType) defaultString += "." + fileType
    }catch(ex){}

    fp.defaultString = defaultString;

    fp.appendFilter(fileType, "*." + fileType);
    var rv = fp.show();
    if (rv == nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
      var file = fp.file;
      var path = fp.file.path;
      return file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It says Window is not defined. fp.init(window, "Save As", nsIFilePicker.modeSave);

Comment: This code is meant for a traditional Firefox add-on, whereas you seem to be using the Add-on SDK.

Comment: oh yes @canuckistani is right. This code works perfectly for traditional firefox addon

Comment: window fix:
var window = require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow();